# Typsescript/React Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Possible duplicate but I am getting "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never[]'" in my React/Typescript project, I have looked up the solutions but I can't find one that will work with my code.

My current error is with **data.id**.

The code still works but I can't fix the error.

I know it is an issue with the value is expected to be *null*, but I can't figure out how to make the value expected to be a string.

```
import LoadingOverlay from 'react-loading-overlay-ts';

export default function App() {
    const [data, setdata] = useState([]);
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(true)
    const getData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
            "https://myapi.xyz/users/details"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setdata(data);
        setActive(value => !value)
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);
    return (
        <LoadingOverlay
      active={isActive}
      spinner
    >
        <div className="App">
            <p> {data.id} </p>
        </div>
            </LoadingOverlay>
    );
}
```

Comment: `useState<your type goes here>([])`

Comment: Also, your `data` is an array, why would it have an `id` property?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not correct and it is a bad practice to use any type over and over but I think you are not aware of what the type of your data will be so you can do below solution:

```
const [data, setdata] = useState<any[]>([]);
```